# If $h(x)=f(g(f(x)))$ is bijective, what do we know about $f,g$?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, functional-equations

**Question:** If $h(x)=f(g(f(x)))$ as a function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bijective, what do we know about $f,g$, which are also functions $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$? Is my proof correct?

**My attempt:** $f$ must be injective. If not, there exist $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, but then $f(g(f(a)))=f(g(f(b)))$, which contradicts the fact that $h$ is injective.

$f$ must be surjective. If there is a value that is not taken by $f$, then it is certainly not taken by $h(x)=f(g(f(x)))$, contradicting that it is bijective.

Suppose there exist $a,b$ such that $g(a)=g(b)$. Because $f$ is surjective, $a,b$ are in the range of $f$, and thus there exist $c,d$ such that $g(f(c))=g(f(d))$, and thus $f(g(f(c)))=f(g(f(d)))$, which contradicts the fact that $h$ is injective. Therefore $g$ is injective.

Since $f$ is bijective, there is an unique $x$ such that $f(x)=p$. If $x$ is not in the range of $g$, then $p$ is not in the range of $h(x)=f(g(f(x)))$, contradicting that it is surjective. Therefore all real numbers are in the range of $g$, thus $g$ is surjective.

Therefore both $f$ and $g$ are bijective.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Small aside: The notation $f\circ g \circ h \circ \cdots$ might prove to be neater than brackets.

Comment: @ZainPatel But how would I do that if I wanted to write $g(f(c))$? $g \circ f(c)$?

Comment: Why not $(g \circ f)(c)$?

Comment: Yes! But after showing the bijectivity of f you can write $g = f^{-1}\circ h \circ f^{-1}$ and this shows immediately that $g$ is also bijective.

Comment: @wythagoras Exactly. It means you don't need to add "$)))))))$" to the end of a lot of nested functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is fine. It's also worth noting that proving $g$ is bijective could be done by considering the inverse of $f$ (there is an inverse because $f$ is bijective). Then,
$$h = f \circ g \circ f \implies f^{-1} \circ h \circ f^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ f \circ g \circ f \circ f^{-1} = g,$$
so $g$ is the composition of three bijections, and hence is bijective.

Comment: This is a beautiful argument and certainly one to remember.